# Form events used from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to store the code below in another class called `RecordAddControl`?

Code from "RecordAdd.cs"

```
private void txtEilesNum_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtEilesNum.Clear();
    txtEilesNum.ForeColor = SystemColors.Desktop;
}

private void txtEilesNum_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtEilesNum.Text == "")
    {
        txtEilesNum.ForeColor = SystemColors.InactiveCaption;
        txtEilesNum.Text = "Eil Num";
    }
}
```

Things I've tried like `RecordAdd recordAdd = new RecordAdd();` doesn't seem to work when trying to get the class to recognise things like `txtEilesNum`.

`RecordAdd` is a form, and `txtEilesNum` is taken from "RecordAdd.Designer.cs"

Comment: how is `txtFilesNum` is defined in your class? Probably it´s `private`, isn´t it? Please show some more code and how you want to access that member.

Comment: It's not defined in the class itself. It's taken from `RecordAdd.Designer.cs`

Comment: What is the `RecordAdd` class? is it a Form?

Comment: Yes, `RecordAdd` is a form

Comment: Then it is a textfield that which is only defined within your `Record`-class. Usually it´s a bad idea to access controls from other classes. What you want instead is usually just a single member of that control. e.g. its current `Text`-value. So pass that around instead of the entire control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it makes more sense to tailor helper class to work with TextBox directly (any TextBox, not only the one in RecordAdd)

```
public static class TexBoxDecorator
{
    public static void UsePlaceholder(this TextBox tb)
    {
        tb.Enter += tb_Enter;
        tb.Leave += tb_Leave;
    }

    private static void tb_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = (TextBox)sender;
        tb.Clear();
        tb.ForeColor = SystemColors.Desktop;
    }

    private static void tb_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = (TextBox)sender;
        if (tb.Text == "")
        {
            tb.ForeColor = SystemColors.InactiveCaption;
            tb.Text = "Eil Num";
        }
    }
}
```

txtEilesNum in a known member in RecordAdd, so it can be accessed to add event handlers:

```
txtEilesNum.UsePlaceholder();
```

Comment: I like this solution, I might be tempted to give it a more descriptive name like `UsePlaceholder()` or something for the decorator

Comment: @Jamiec, yeah, I guess if this code sets input hint, then your suggested name will improve readability. also to make it fully reusable, one will have to customize hint text, e.g. `tb.Text = (string)tb.Tag;` (need some way to get custom text)

Comment: I get an error on `tb_Enter` and `tb_Leave` saying 



"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Control.tb_Enter(object,EventArgs)'"

Comment: Oh, so i can only reference static methods with other static methods?

Comment: it is possible to use non-static method, but only if you have an intance of object to which they belong.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can store event handlers in another class, you'll need to make them public, and you'll need to cast the `sender` to the correct type:

```
public static class EventHandlers
{
    public void EilesNum_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var txtEilesNum = (TextBox)sender; // Assumed textbox
        txtEilesNum.Clear();
        txtEilesNum.ForeColor = SystemColors.Desktop;
    }
    public void EilesNum_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var txtEilesNum = (TextBox)sender; // Also assumed textbox
        if(txtEilesNum.Text == "")
        {
            txtEilesNum.ForeColor = SystemColors.InactiveCaption;
            txtEilesNum.Text = "Eil Num";
        }
    }
}
```

In your form, you'll still need to wire up the events as before

```
txtEilesNum.Enter += EventHandlers.EilesNum_Enter;
txtEilesNum.Leave += EventHandlers.EilesNum_Leave;
```